# Running expressions (without compilation of files) in Makefile without targets?

Tags: makefile

I wanted to test some expressions of the `ifeq` kind that run a shell command that I read somewhere, so I wrote this tiny `mymakefile` (all lines being indented with a tab):

```make
    ifeq ($(shell echo test 2>/dev/null; echo $$?),0)
            $(info I am inside)
    endif
```

... and I tried to run it:

```
$ make -f mymakefile 
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

How could I test expressions like this inside their own makefile? Do I need to define a default target, or not? And how should the commands be formatted (indented with a tab, or space, or not indented at all?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got somewhere - apparently, one must specify a target; but since I'm a `make` noob, I would love to see a more qualified answer.

I found this link https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html that gave me a hint.. Anyways, this is `mymakefile` now:

```make
.PHONY: default
default: mytarget;

ifeq ($(shell echo test 2>/dev/null; echo $$?),0)
$(info I am inside)
else
$(info I am outside)
endif

mytarget:
\t (TAB) echo A
```

So, the `mytarget` here is just a dummy, which simply does an `echo A`; running this prints:

```
$ make -f mymakefile 
I am outside
echo A
A
```

If you don't want the `echo A` printed, suppress it with at sign: `@echo A`.

The `echo A` line has to be indented with a TAB - else error "`mymakefile:11: *** missing separator.  Stop.`".

Strangely, if I indent the two `$(info...` lines with a TAB, then "`I am outside`" is printed last (?!), but when they are not indented (or indented with spaces), then it is printed first (as per the order in the file).